# Django 'redirect_field_name' why it returns to index.html page?

Tags: django

after filling the form when I click on save to redirect to 'clinichospital_list.html' but it takes to index.html.
it is view.py class

```
class ClinicHospitalCreateView(CreateView):
redirect_field_name = 'clinichospital_detail.html'
form_class = ClinicHospitalForm
model = ClinicHospital
```

it is urls.py

```
path(r'',views.AboutView.as_view(),name = 'about'),
**path(r'^list/$',views.ClinicHospitalListView.as_view(),name ='clinichospital_list' ),**
path(r'^clinichospital/(?P<pk>\d)/$',views.ClinicHospitalDetailView.as_view(),name = 'clinichospital_detail'),
path(r'^clinichospital/new/$',views.ClinicHospitalCreateView.as_view(),name = 'clinichospital_new'),
path(r'^clinichospital/(?P<pk>\d)/edit/$',views.ClinicHospitalUpdateView.as_view(), name = 'clinichospital_eidt'),
path(r'^clinichospital/(?P<pk>\d)/remove/$',views.ClinicHospitalDeleteView.as_view(),name = 'clinichospital_remove'),
```

and it is forms.py

```
<form class="clinic-form"  method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}
<button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default" name="button">Save</button>
```

Comment: it is not forms.py it is clinicForm.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, a `CreateView` has no `redirect_field_name`, hence it will not take that into account in the logic behind the `CreateView`.

Furthermore you are here confusing a *template* with a *path*. In Django paths normally have no `.html` (or other) extensions. Multiple *paths* can render the *same* template, hence it would not make much sense anyway.

You can override the [**`get_success_url(..)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_success_url) and return the corresponding path:

```
from django.urls import reverse

class ClinicHospitalCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = ClinicHospitalForm
    model = ClinicHospital

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('clinichospital_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

Note that your paths use [**`re_path(..)`** syntax [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.re_path) instead of [**`path(..)`** syntax [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.path). You can rewrite these to:

```
path('',views.AboutView.as_view(), name='about'),
path('list',views.ClinicHospitalListView.as_view(), name='clinichospital_list' ),
path('clinichospital/<int:pk>',views.ClinicHospitalDetailView.as_view(), name='clinichospital_detail'),
path('clinichospital/new/',views.ClinicHospitalCreateView.as_view(), name='clinichospital_new'),
path('clinichospital/<int:pk>/edit/',views.ClinicHospitalUpdateView.as_view(), name='clinichospital_edit'),
path('clinichospital/<int:pk>/remove/',views.ClinicHospitalDeleteView.as_view(), name='clinichospital_remove'),
```